# Select control not joining/matching up within input-group with 2 other controls (a text input and input-group-btn)

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an input-group of 3 controls. The following :

```
                      1. Filter dropdown of sort (Currently using <select>
                      2. The input text box
                      3. The Search button
```

I've managed to get the latter 2 working as expected, they both join up and appear as expected however when I try to add a select control although in-line it doesn't seem to have the same height as the other 2 controls. I've tried all sorts of combinations and have ran out of ideas to try.

[image: non-matching control heights image]

On the bootstrap documentation they have not shown how to do this with a  but with a dropdown  control however when I tried to do that with  I could not get it to work as the  control does.

Could someone suggest how I could add the filter control? Here is an example of the data in my angular controller $scope.filterOptions = ["test", "test2", "test3"].

What I essentially what to achieve is something similar to that of the bootstrap documentation example :

[image: bootstrap control group]

Here's the non-working html I have at the moment.

```
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <form class="input-group col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="filterOption">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <option ng-repeat="option in filterOptions" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ID / Name">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button ng-click="search()" type="submit" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here's a plunkr I made which shows the same problem : http://plnkr.co/edit/uDFmFZSbIMBP4DqalhQC?p=preview

Comment: Thanks that works brilliantly, could you please make that as an answer so I can select it as such.

Comment: It's worth noting that Bootstrap [has a box warning about the cross-browser compat issues](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) associated with doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height of the `select` compared to the `button` in the bootstrap [example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns) is less so giving a height to the select will make it same as other controls.

By default

CSS

```
select {height: 34px;}
```

[Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pdk6w3tmVctNkbQ7LVYY?p=preview)